# Why does my struct cost so much performance?

Tags: c#, struct

I've been debugging for so long now, and I figured that the reason why my program is running so slow is due to the following struct:

```
public struct PlayerData
{
    public float time;

    // player movement
    public bool forward;
    public bool backward;
    public bool leftward;
    public bool rightward;
    public bool crouch;
    public bool jump;

    // items
    public bool primaryFire;
    public bool secondaryFire;
    public bool firstSlot;
    public bool secondSlot;
    public bool thirdSlot;

    // state
    public Vector3 position;
    public Vector3 velocity;
    public Vector3 viewDirection;
}
```

If I remove a few fields from the struct, the program runs faster. I tried removing all the bools, and the program ran significantly faster. The same occurred with removing the Vector3s. Also, the performance difference is enormous. My program is running at ~200fps with *half* of those fields omitted, but I would be lucky to break 10fps with all those fields.

Should I convert it to a class? Am I using structs incorrectly? Why is my struct so slow?

Comment: What happens if you convert it to a class?

Comment: It's not clear what the issue would be, without seeing the code that's using this struct (a struct, by itself, really isn't doing anything...). And you're talking about fps, so maybe there's some type of tight loop you have, doing some struct manipulation? Please edit your question to include more details, especially with the relevant code manipulating these struct instances.

Comment: You might benefit from `Span<T>` though your code looks like Unity and I doubt it is supported there.

Comment: We really need to know how this data is *used* in order to evaluate it in any meaningfull way. Bool values in themselves should not cause such problems, but accessing them again and again continually might - it actualy depends on your *logic*. The code you've included so far does not contain logic - only fields for holding data.

Comment: Check task manager and see how much memory you are using.  there is no reason that the structure is causing slow performance.

Comment: Indeed, why not use a class. A such struct is heavy especially if you pass instances from methods to methods in chain and you saturate the stack by using a lot of CPU clocks in pushes and pops as if you are handling dinosaurs in a mansion full of doors like some comic movies where everyone is looking for. I exaggerate.

Comment: Have you used the Visual Studio's profiling tools to determine where it slows down ?

Comment: Try passing as `ref` or `in` to avoid copying of the struct.

Comment: Structs have to be copied when assigned. Compilers will often inline the copy routine if the struct is small, calling memcpy() for larger structs. Then there's cpu cache lines.... Try to "restructure" (heh) your code to avoid copies and the size wont matter as much, using `ref`, `readonly`, `stackalloc` as much as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your structure is 52 bytes in size.  It breaks down like this:

- `float` - 1 field, 4 bytes
- `bool` - 11 fields, 1 byte each
- `Vector3` - 3 fields, 12 bytes each (each containing 3 floats)

`(1 x 4) + (11 x 1) + (12 x 3)` = 51 bytes for the fields themselves.  Then, due to data structure alignment within the struct, the size is increased to 52 bytes in this case.

You can see this yourself with `sizeof(PlayerData)`.

The [.NET Framework design guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct) state that structs should generally be 16 bytes *maximum*.  I think this may be higher now with .NET Core, but I cannot seem to find a reference.  Either way, 52 bytes is way too large for a struct to perform well.

Keep in mind that even though a boolean is just a true/false value, the boolean data type still takes up 1 byte (8 bits) of memory, again due to data structure alignment.  Since you have so many booleans, you might consider using a [`BitVector32`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32), which can store 32 separate boolean values in only 4 bytes.

However, you still have 3 `Vector3`'s taking up the majority of the structure, and unless you actually need less than what they provide, there's no getting those smaller.  Thus, you really should be using a `class` rather than a `struct`.

Comment: The weight management of a struct does not depends if this is .NET Framework or Core or any other, but on CPU architecture, capabilities and performances on using the CPU stack pushe and pop system to pass value types and all content for structs and to get results of CPU proc calls... Under .NET there is machine code and the CPU x86, ARM and so on. While waiting for .NET CPUs...

Answer (score 3):

As an idea. Consider [`FlagsAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute?view=netframework-4.8)

```cs
[Flags]
public enum Movement : byte
{
    Idle = 0,
    Forward = 1,
    Backward = 2,
    Leftward = 4,
    Rightward = 8,
    Crouch = 16,
    Jump = 32
}

public struct PlayerData
{
    // ...
    public Movement movestate;
    // ...
}
```

Usage

```cs
// add flag
data.movestate |= Movement.Jump;
// remove flag
date.movestate &= ~Movement.Crouch;
// check flag
if (data.movestate.HasFlag(Movement.Forward)) { ... }
// reset all
data.movestate = Movement.Idle;
```

Comment: What is more efficient between using a flagged enum or a BitVector32, except that last is limited to 4 bytes ?

Comment: @OlivierRogier ... or bunch of bools? I don't know.

Comment: A flags enum is indeed a good idea.  Since this enum derives from `byte`, it takes just 1 byte, whereas a `BitVector32` takes 4 (as would an enum derived from `int`).  Just depends on how many actual states you need.

Comment: A byte needs a 32-bits register on x32 or a 64-bits on x64 systems. After a night of reflection, using enum is better because here we manipulate just one byte (that is an int32 or in64 in the CPU like using a large road for a little vehicule) with bitwise operators. It is the most optimized because BitVector32 use some references and CPU proc calls clocks for methods. The advantage of BitVector32 is to offer a less experimented way and a more OOP way to do such things and more: [bitvector32.cs](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/compmod/system/collections/specialized/bitvector32.cs)